# show div class on keyup hide otherwise jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery. I need to hide a button and hours_div at the beginning and show only when the hours form is clicked on. But hidden at first.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(function () {

  $("#hours_div").trigger('keyup');
  $('.phone_button #hours_div').show();
```

I added everything I could to make it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/1uu1uc7c/

Comment: Can you please draw the scenario in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/events/ - especially http://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/

Comment: Also it is not quite clear why you have used trigger. Please tell the requirement clearly. It should be a trivial jquery function.

Comment: if both div and button are hidden, then what will you click to show them up?

Comment: I will click any hours form box. So I will be clicking the hours form then the button and div will appear on a mobile phone interface graphic.

Comment: You really need to do some research before posting a question like this. Your jsfiddle is using jQuery, yet you do not even have the jQuery library included. You mention a hours form, yet there is no hours form included in your html.

Comment: may you want to search more before you ask a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/1uu1uc7c/3/

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
<!-- CSS -->
#extra-options {
    display:none;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<form id='form' class='form'>
    Click Here
</form>
<div id='extra-options'>
    <div class="button">
        My button
    </div>
    <div id="hours_div">
        Hours
    </div>
</div>

<!-- JQuery -->
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").click(function() {
       $("#extra-options").show(); 
    });
});
```